# Duck Spyder as a launcher which is installed through Anaconda on Ubuntu17.4

Tags: anaconda, spyder

After installing Anaconda(3 or higher) it includes Spyder. So it isn't known as an independent application. The problem with this kind of having Spyder is that Ubuntu doesn't allow to Duck it or add a Spyder shortcut on  Desktop or add it as a Favorite. Therefore, every time I need to run Spyder, I have to run it through command line: `$ spyder`   which is not the best and a fast way to run it.

On the other hand, I already have spyder and based on it's official website is not recommended to have it double installed: https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html

So I need a way which allows me to have a shortcut for my Spyder on Desktop or Favorites list or on Duck.

Comment: Please complete your list of examples in the future. This ``...`` doesn't help at *all*.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JensHöpken I edited the post, hope it's clear now.

Comment: similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031787/959929)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after searching a lot, here is what has worked for me: Copy any launcher from:

`/usr/share/applications/`.

Right click and go to properties, change the command line to spyder path:

`~/anaconda3/bin/spyder` or     `~/anaconda/bin/spyder`

> **Note:** You can get the correct spyder path by typing:     `$ which spyder`

Change the rest of the info like description and icon path as you like.

Save the file under something like *spyder.desktop* in order to set it as a desktop configuration file.

Now you have a app launcher which is connected to spyder (in Anaconda), copy the launcher to:

`~/.local/share/applications/`

Now the icon should pop up in your application menu.

> **Note:** You should set the *user* as the owner. So this is the last step:
>
> `sudo chown <username> ~/.local/share/applications/spyder.desktop`

Comment: I tried this method but spyder wouldn't start. Finally I found out the shortcut didn't start because it's owner was set to _root_. It worked as soon as I changed the owner.